# Php code works on every browser but not on IE8

Tags: php

I think the error has to be in a incompatibility with IE8 and the cookies manipulation, cuz in IE8 you can see the password and login asking screen but when you enter the data and send it the browser seems to do nothing, this is a url you were you can try my code: http://200.8.27.127/tiempo/teacher.php

and this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="it" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Formulario</title>
<style type="text/css">
h1 {    font: 50px Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; text-align: center; color: #111; text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;    }
h2 {    font: 14px Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; text-align: center; color: #CCC; text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #555;    }
h3 {    font: 10px Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; text-align: center; color: #CCC;   }
b1 {    font: 16px Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; color: #DDD;   }
b2 {    font: 10px Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; color: #F9F7ED;    }

.caja {  width: 690px; height: 40px; background-color: transparent; border: 0px solid #000000; font-size:x-large; color: #222; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;" size="299";  }
.style1 {   text-align: right; }
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-image: url('IMG/bg.png')">
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.notifications-1.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="JS/jquery.notifications.css" />
<script> function checkCharCount(textfield) { if(textfield.value.length > 300) textfield.value = textfield.value.substr(0, 300); document.getElementById("charCounter").innerHTML = 300 - textfield.value.length; } </script>
<?php
include("/LIB/HeadSQL.php");
include("/LIB/error.php");
if (isset($_COOKIE['ID_tablon'])) { 
        $username = $_COOKIE['ID_tablon']; 
        $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_tablon'];
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
        while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check )) {
            if ($pass != $info['clave']) {
                login();
            }
            else {
                entro($info['email'],$username);
            }
        }
} else {
    login();
}


function login()
{
    if (isset($_POST['quiere'])) {
        if(!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['pass']) {
            include("LIB/login.php");
            error('Debes llenar todos los campos.',0);
        } else {
            $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = '".$_POST['username']."'") or die(mysql_error());
            $check2 = mysql_num_rows($check);
            if ($check2 == 0) {
                include("LIB/login.php");
                error('Ese usuario no existe.',0);
            }
            while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check )) {
                $_POST['pass'] = stripslashes($_POST['pass']);
                $info['clave'] = stripslashes($info['clave']);
                //$_POST['pass'] = md5($_POST['pass']);
                if ($_POST['pass'] != $info['clave']) {
                    include("LIB/login.php");
                    error('La clave es incorrecta.',0);
                } else { 
                    $_POST['username'] = stripslashes($_POST['username']); 
                    $hour = time() + 3600; 
                    setcookie("ID_tablon", $_POST['username'], $hour); 
                    setcookie("Key_tablon", $_POST['pass'], $hour); 
                    entro($info['email'],$_POST['username']);
                }
            } 
        } 
    } else {
        include("LIB/login.php");
    }
    exit;
}


function entro($email,$username)
{
?>

<div id="todo" align="center" >
    <div id="cabeza" style="width:850px;height:100px">
    </div>
    <div id="contenido" style="width:850px;height:420px;background-image: url(IMG/cuadro.png)" >
        <div id="titulo" style="width:765px;height:75px;padding-top: 18px;margin: auto;text-align: left;">
            <b1>Bienvenido <b><?php echo($username); ?></b></b1><br>
            <?php $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sms WHERE ref = '".$username."' ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 0, 1") or die(mysql_error());
            while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check )) { 
                echo("<b1> Tu ultimo mensaje enviado fue: </b1><b2>" . $info['texto'] . " enviado el " . $info['fecha'] . "</b2>");
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <form method="post">
        <div id="formulario" style="width:850px;height:255px;margin-top: 10px">
            <div id="foto" align="right" style="width:725px; height:40px;padding-top: 11px;margin: auto">
                <?php $size = 60; $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5( strtolower( $email ) ) . "?size=" . $size; 
                $size = 256; $grav_urlB = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5( strtolower( $email ) ) . "?size=" . $size;
                echo('<img alt="Image" src="' . $grav_url . '" />'); ?>
            </div>
            <div id="texto" style="width:850px;height:29px; margin-top: 38px;margin-left: 4px">
                    <input name="sms" type="text"  onKeyUp="checkCharCount(this)" class="caja"  />
            </div>
            <div id="botones" style="width:725px;height:27px; margin-top: 15px" class="style1">
                <input name="usuario" type="hidden" value="<?php echo($username); ?>" />

                <input name="Submit1" type="image" value="submit" src="IMG/envia.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="resta" style="width:850px;height:29px; margin-top: 53px;margin-left: 4px">
                <h2><span id="charCounter">300</span> caracteres restantes.</h2>
                <h3><a href=logout.php>Cerrar Sesion</a></h3>
            </div> 

        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>


<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && (time() - $_SESSION['token']) < 5) {
   error('Debes esperar 5 segundos para poder enviar otra informacion.',0);
} else { 
   $_SESSION['token'] = time();
   include("/LIB/HeadSQL.php");
   include("/LIB/comprueba.php");
   $insert = "INSERT INTO sms (ref, texto, fecha) VALUES ('" . addslashes($_POST['usuario']) . "', '" . addslashes($_POST['sms']) . "', NOW() )";
   $add_member = mysql_query($insert);
   error("Tu mensage ha sido enviado con exito.",1);
}
}
    exit;
}
?>
```

do you think the isuue can be on the javascript?

**try the code firts with Firefox or google chrome, then try in IE8.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely the JS. PHP is a server-side language, which means it only has to work on your server... the same content gets sent to the client regardless of what browser they are using. That said, I don't know where specifically the error lies in your JS. You're using jQuery... why not take advantage of it? Get rid of that

```
document.getElementById("charCounter").innerHTML
```

And replace it with

```
$('#charCounter').html(...)
```

For instance... jQuery is built for cross-browser compatibility, so use it as much as possible.

Comment: document.getElementById("charCounter").innerHTML = 300 - textfield.value.length;

Are you allowed to set innerHTML to a number?  Is it implicitly converted to a string?

you could try:
document.getElementById("charCounter").innerHTML = "" + (300 - textfield.value.length);

Comment: Its not, i must add to my questions:

Try the user: djsoftlayer and password: 1234

IN FIREFOX you will get access but not in IE8

Please try this